# How to define quarter-chord sweep angle for a cranked wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, commercial-aviation

I have the values for surface area, span, aspect ratio, and quarter chord sweep angle, etc., for a general trapezoidal planform. So, I changed my wing to a single cranked wing such that surface area and span doesn't change. Therefore, parameters like root chord, tip chord, etc., changed. Now, for the, cranked wing how to define quarter-chord or half-chord sweep angles?

Comment: I think adding a drawing of your wing can help mental representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to define the sweep angles for every section on the cranked wing. You can use the same definition for each segment as for a "normal" wing. So practically speaking: Root Segment quarter chord --> create line between quarter chord of root and quarter chord of kink. Then you can measure the sweep angle of the root segment. Continue with next segment. The quarter-chord sweep angle is the angle between the y axis and the quarter chord line.

[image]

Comment: So, one cannot define the quarter chord sweep angle for the whole cranked wing?

Comment: Of course you can do it, but what would you do with that? Usually you are using these parameters for aerodynamic analysis, so you have to analyze every panel seperately. For example the Drag Divergence Numbers for each Panel. When do they become supersonic and how does the neutral point shift in the transonic/supersonic regime etc.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks!